# Jena model.write get InvalidPropertyURIException

Tags: java, xml, uri, jena

I' m using jena, and get this exception when writing the model. I don' t know why it doesn' t tell you when you create the property URI.

```
 com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.InvalidPropertyURIException:     http://name.space/%E7%AB%A3%E5%B7%A5%E6%97%B6%E9%97%B4
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.splitTag(BaseXMLWriter.java:384)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.tag(BaseXMLWriter.java:396)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.startElementTag(BaseXMLWriter.java:355)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.Basic.writePredicate(Basic.java:101)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.Basic.writeRDFStatements(Basic.java:85)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.Basic.writeRDFStatements(Basic.java:74)
```

Currently I use

```
DatatypeProperty datatypeProperty = model.createDatatypeProperty(nameSpace+URIref.encode(string));
```

to create the datatype property, using **URIref.encode** to encode the string, is it wrong?

Comment: "I don' t know why it doesn' t tell you when you create the property URI."  As AndyS's answer indicates, it's not necessarily that the URI is invalid (as a URI), but rather that it's invalid **for that particular serialization**.  If you had tried to write the model in a different format (e.g., Turtle, N-Triples), then you might not get this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.splitTag` does not accept this property URI. See also `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.splitNamespace` and code examples http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.XSD (search for `createDatatypeProperty`):

`String ns = "http://www.example.org/test#";
 DatatypeProperty p = model.createDatatypeProperty( ns + "p" );`

Comment: Yes - there are some impossible IRIs for RDF/XML.
  
"%B4" -> "4" is illegal for a qname local part (starts with a number)

"%B4" -> "B4" is illegal because the possible namespace URI now ends in "%".

You can write in a different format instead.  Also, consider why you are encoding the URI path at all.

Comment: Can I check if the URI is valid when adding( createIndividual()), instead of getting the error when writing model to output?

Comment: You can use the same checking code - Util.splitNamespace and test whether the split point is the same length as the input string.